# Impact of epsilon in the Q-learning process?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am in the process of learning Reinforcement Learning. I understood the general idea of RL.

However, so far I am yet to understand what is the impact of  in RL? What should be the recommended value?

When `=1`, does it imply explore randomly? If this intuition is correct, then it will not learn anything with `=1`.

On the other hand, if we set =0 that will imply do not explore and in this case agent will not learn anything either.

I am wondering whether my intuition is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

## What does epsilon control?

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning

> with probability *epsilon*, exploration is chosen, and the action is chosen uniformly at random.

This means that with a probability equal to epsilon the system will ignore what it has learnt so far and effectively stumble or jerk blindly to the next state.  That kinds sounds ridiculous as a strategy and certainly if I saw a pedestrian sometimes flailing randomly as they walked down the street I wouldn't say they were 'exploring'.

So, how is this exploring in something like q-learning or RL?  If instead of small actions like flailing the the pedestrian example, if we are talking about larger logical moves then trying something new once in a while, like walking north first then east instead of always east first then north, may take us by a nice icecream shop, or game reward.

Depending on what kinds of actions your q-learning or RL system controls, adding various levels (*epsilon*) of noisy actions will help.

Let's take a look at two scenarios:

1. A 8x8 grid, some reward squares, a final goal square, and some 'evil' squares.
2. A Call-Of-Duty like game, a FPS in a huge open world with few rewards other than after several minutes of play, with each second of game play involving several controller movements.

In the first one, if we have an epsilon of .1, that means 10% of the time we just move at random. If we are right beside an 'evil' square, that means even if the RL has learnt that it needs to not move to the 'evil' square, it has a 10% of moving randomly, and if it does than a 1/4 chance of moving to the 'evil' square... so a 2.5% of just dying for no reason whenever beside an 'evil' square.  It will have to navigate across the 8x8, and if it is set up like a maze between 'evil' squares and the start is opposite the end, then there will be about 20 or so moves.  With a 10% error rate, that will be about 20 to 24 moves once it has reached mastery.  When it just starts out, its informed moves are no better than random and it will have a 1/4^20 chance of making it the first time.  Alternatively, if it learns some path that is sub-optimal, the only method it has to learn the optimal path is for its random moves (*epsilon*) to happen at the right time and in the right direction.  That can take a really really long time if we need 5 correct random moves to happen in a row (1/10^5 x 1/4^5)

Now let's look at the FPS game with millions of moves.  Each move isn't so critical.  So an epsilon of .1 (10%) isn't so bad.  On the flip side, the number of random moves that need to be chained together to make a meaningful new move or follow a path is astronomically large.  Setting a higher epsilon (like .5) will certainly increase the chance, but we still have the issue of branching factor.  If in order to go all the way down a new alley way we need 12 seconds of game play with 5 actions per second, then that's 60 actions in a row.  There is a 1/2^60 chance of getting 60 random new moves in a row to go down this alleyway when the RL has a belief to not to.  That doesn't really sound like an exploration factor to me.

But it does work for toy problems.

## Lots of possibilities to improve it

If we frame the RL problem just a little differently, we can get really different results.

Let's say instead of *epsilon* meaning that we do something random for one time step, it instead is the chance of switching states between: using RL to guide our actions or doing one thing continuously (go north, chop wood).  In either state we switch to the other with chance *epsilon*.

In the FPS game example, if we had an *epsilon* of 1/15 , then for about 15 steps (5 steps per second, this is 3 seconds on average) we would have RL control our moves, then for 3 seconds it would do just one thing (run north, shoot the sky, ...) then back to RL.  This will be a lot less like a pedestrian twitching as they walked, and instead more like once in a while running north and then west.